# AWS Cognito with google provider, how to handle the response from google?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-cognito

So I'm using cognito User Pools with Google as an Identity provider. I configured everything and I'm sending the data to google, which redirects back to the amazon auth endpoint, which then redirects back to my app with the following parameters in the URL:

```
AccessToken
ExpiresIn
IdToken
TokenType
```

Now, I have no idea how to use these to actually create a Cognito "session" that goes into the javascript api workflow and just becomes automatic (sending, receiving and renewing the token)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Using IDToken to Authenticate Your API**

After you authenticate, you can cache the IDToken in Browser and use it when the logged in user requests for API Calls from your web or mobile application. Then you can validate the token at your API endpoints for each request.

**Validating IDToken**

For more information about using the tokens and validating it at API endpoints, refer [AWS documentation on Using Tokens with User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html). There is a new library introduced by AWS called [aws-amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) which simplify some of the implementations. If you are using AWS API Gateway for your API, you can use a custom authorizer Lambda function to do the validation.

**Storing the IDToken and Security**

In addition, the IDToken is a stateless token, which means it doesn't have a session in connection with AWS Cognito Once issued. Which means you cannot revoke it after issuing. Therefore it's important to keep its expiry short.

To allow your authentication API to issue new IDTokens before it gets expired, you might need to store the Refresh Token in your backend and use it to issue new tokens before the IDToken expires to implement a sliding window.

Note: Storing the IDToken in browser, you can decide in using multiple storage options available (E.g; Cookies, LocalStorage). However, I'm not going to comment on the security implications since it is itself a long discussion where there are still opinionated areas. The standard approach currently available, is to set up a serverside Cookie and implement CSRF. It will be challenging to implement unless you use the IDToken just to initiate the authentication and use a session instead, for the recurring requests.